# Get Folder Name of %1 Parameter for a Batch File

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to write a batch script to push folder using Android ADB.

The commands I am trying to achieve is :

```
c:\adbpush.bat d:\Android\XDA\Bootlogo
```

How do I get the string Bootlogo ?

I want to do something like this

```
@echo off
c:
cd \adb
adb push d:\Android\XDA\Bootlogo /sdcard/Bootlogo
```

Looks simple but I don't have any idea how to get string `Bootlogo` From `d:\Android\XDA\Bootlogo`

I hope you guys understand. Thanks A Lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your command line

```
c:\adbpush.bat d:\Android\XDA\Bootlogo
```

Then this should work for you:

```
::adbpush.bat
@echo off
cd /d "c:\adb"
adb push %~1 \sdcard\%~nx1
```

Comment: Nice Snippet, actually I need to change it a little to make it works


adb push "%~1" "/sdcard/%~nx1"

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, the quotes are needed for long filename elements - your example didn't use them and I couldn't assume that the adb tool supported them, so I left them out.  Glad it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ("%~1") do set yourstring=%%~nxa
echo %yourstring%
```

shoud get that info for you.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could get it from batch file via powershell split-path -Leaf function.

Command

```
c:\adbpush.bat d:\Android\XDA\Bootlogo
```

adbpush.bat

```
@ECHO OFF
start /b powershell -command "$a = Split-Path -Leaf -Path %1;Write-Host $a"
PAUSE
```

Result

```
Bootlogo
```